# How to check the type of a field before checking the value in rethinkdb?

Tags: typeof, rethinkdb

I have few tables in rethinkdb with very varied datasets. Mostly because over time, out of simple string properties complex objects were created to be more expressive.

When I run a query, I'm making sure that all fields exist, with the [hasFields - function](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/has_fields/). But what if I want to run a RegExp query on my `Message` property, which can be of type string or object. Of course if it is an object, I don't care about the row, but instead of ignoring it, rethinkdb throws the error:

> Unhandled rejection RqlRuntimeError: Expected type STRING but found OBJECT in...

Can I somehow use [typeOf](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/type_of/#) to first determine the type, before running the query?

Or what would be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not 100% clear to me so I'm going to restate the problem to make sure my solution gets sense.

**Problem**

Get all documents where the `message` property is of type `object` or the `message` property is a string and matches a particular regular expression (using the [`match`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/match/) method).

**Solution**

You basically need an `if` statement. For that, you can use the [`r.branch`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/branch/) to 'branch' your conditions depending on these things.

Here's a very long, but clear example on how to do this:

Let's say you have these documents and you want all documents where the `message` property is an object or a string that has the substring 'string'. The documents look like this:

```
{
  "id":  "a1a17705-e7b0-4c84-b9d5-8a51f4599eeb" ,
  "message":  "invalid"
}, {
  "id":  "efa3e26f-2083-4066-93ac-227697476f75" ,
  "message":  "this is a string"
}, {
 "id":  "80f55c96-1960-4c38-9810-a76aef60d678" ,
  "not_messages": "hello"
}, {
  "id":  "d59d4e9b-f1dd-4d23-a3ef-f984c2361226" ,
  "message": {
    "exists": true ,
    "text":  "this is a string"
  }
}
```

For that , you can use the following query:

```
r.table('messages')
  .hasFields('message') // only get document with the `message` property
  .filter(function (row) { 
    return r.branch( // Check if it's an object
      row('message').typeOf().eq('OBJECT'), // return true if it's an object
      true,
      r.branch( // Check if it's a string
        row('message').typeOf().eq('STRING'),
        r.branch( // Only return true if the `message` property ...
          row('message').match('string'), // has the substring `string`
          true,
          false // return `false` if it's a string but doesn't match our regex
        ),
        false // return `false` if it's neither a string or an object
      )
    )
  })
```

Again this query is long and could be written a lot more elegantly, but it explains the use of [`branch`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/branch/) very clearly.

A shorter way of writing this query is this:

```
r.table('messages')
  .hasFields('message')
  .filter(function (row) {
    return 
      row('message').typeOf().eq('OBJECT')
        .or(
          row('message').typeOf().eq('STRING').and(row('message').match('string'))
        )
  })
```

This basically uses the [`and`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/and/) and [`or`](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/or/) methods instead of `branch`.

Comment: not really the answer to my question, but it very much clarifies how to use the typeOf function, that's all I need, thx very much

Comment: I didn't really understand your question then. Can you clarify what the question was? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: yes, I wanted to just run match if the item is a string and ignore the object, so I can just skip the first part of your condition, but it was also good to see more complex queries as an example, thx

Answer (score 0):

This query will return you all registers on table message that have the field message and the field is String.
Cheers.

```
r.db('test').table('message').hasFields('message')
.filter(function (row) { 
    return row('message').typeOf().eq('STRING')
})
```